# Scripting svg when embedded using <img> tag

Tags: svg

I placed my svg on the page like this:
`<img id="svg" src="my.svg">`

Inside of my.svg,I have en element with id=ship.
How can I access the "ship" from the browser?

P.S. If I inline my svg using  tag, I can use getElementById("ship"). So I want the same, but with "" setting...

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. img elements don't allow you to access their contents. You could use an object or iframe tag instead.

Comment: Or, if you want to keep your SVG in files the CSS needs to be added inside of the SVG file.